# jqPlot in xpages

Tags: json, xpages, jqplot, lotus-domino

Has anyone used jqPlot to build a graph in XPages? If anyone has, did you need to have the xpages extension library? Anyone used any other plotting tools in xpages apart from Dojo?

I am following this tutorial but I don't know how to get the JSON values all in one column like the screenshots show.

http://blog.wilhow.net/2013/03/17/charting-104-in-xpages-connecting-to-notes-document/

The tutorial also says "You will need to define some composite data in the Property Definition tab so that you can pass these values into jqPlot as variables." Does XPages already have jqPlot built in it?

Comment: 1. yes, 2. no, 3. yes, 4. no

Answer (score 4):

Iona,

"..did you need to have the xpages extension library.."

ANS:Extension Library(Ext Lib) is not necessary for the example. Ext lib is geared towards rapid development of certain common features that will be reused frequently in XPages. ie. REST service, Name Picker.

"..Does XPages already have jqPlot built in it?.."

ANS: No. jpPlot is an external library built and maintained separately from XPages.

"...Anyone used any other plotting tools in xpages apart from Dojo?..."

ANS: There are plenty other plotting tool that you can use, a couple that comes to mind KendoUI, Highcharts, google charts. As long as the plotting tool is js based, you should be able to integrate it with XPages fairly easily.

"..I don't know how to get the JSON values all in one column.."

ANS: The column formula for that particular column is shown below. IE,FF,CH,SA,OP are field names.
http://wilhow.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/screen-shot-2013-04-11-at-8-36-09-pm.png

"...define some composite data in the Property Definition tab..."

ANS: The above is true only if you want to follow the example or if you want to create a reusable custom component that plot charts with a set of given values. CompositeData is a feature built into XPages's custom controls to allow values to be received from one custom control that is embedded in another. Below is an example of how a CompositeData is defined and implemented in the example.

http://wilhow.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/compositedata1.png

Unfortunately I'm not able to post any images yet. You will have to follow the link to view the image. In any case, I hope the answer helps.

Cheers,
Wil
[xpages](/questions/tagged/xpages) [xpages-ssjs](/questions/tagged/xpages-ssjs) [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes) [lotus-domino](/questions/tagged/lotus-domino)[jqplot](/questions/tagged/jqplot)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [D3JS](http://d3js.org/). While it comes with a rather steep learning curve (like an Ariadne flight path), it is very flexible in its capabilities. To get data in JSON format I use an outputScript tag and a custom parameter. So in the outputScript I have a line like `var data = #{compositeData.data};` and feed the data using a SSJS.

I have this code to make sure d3js is loaded:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
var scriptTag = "<script src=\"http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js\"><\/script>";
window.d3 || document.write(scriptTag);
})
```

but you could load it from the Domino server too. More code you need to assemble all this are in XSnippets:

- the [SSJS](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=render-a-d3js-bar-chart-part-2) to retrieve data from a view
- the [JS](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=render-a-d3js-bar-chart-part-1) to render a bar chart

Good luck (and yes, it is one of the unfinished draft entries in my blog)

Comment: thank you stwissel for your comment, I've been trying to follow the steps. I now have data in JSON format link this ("["+@Text(temp1)+","+@Text(threshold1)+","+@Text(time1)+"]"). I am working on retrieving data from a view. I assumed that code you sent me a link to needs to go into a JS script library (since I am using xpages)? I am trying to plot a line chart with 3 lines I assume that code should do the job?

Comment: Yes. the SSJS goes into a script library. the JS probably needs modification since you want a line and not a bar chart. The d3js.org site has all the details how to draw a chart of your choosing